# How come Jokowi Build Far More Roads than Other Previous Presidents?

Tags: infrastructure, indonesia

Jokowi followers claim that Jokowi build many more TOL roads than previous presidents.

The roads are also build at "fair price" rather than inflated corrupt price.

[image]

Some people are discussing this. Putting some skeptical analysis
https://tirto.id/jokowi-bangun-tol-lebih-panjang-dari-sby-amp-presiden-sebelumnya-cYvo

Detractors of Jokowi says that the tol roads have been built since SBY and Jokowi is just "finishing"

How does Jokowi compares compared to others, especially on these Tol roads building enterprise?

Comment: This question is better suited on [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, try to add references for these pictures. AFAIK, the claim must be notable on Skeptics, so an online reference would be welcomed.

Comment: Yes, this is a fact-checking question for Skeptics.SE. However, I can not migrate it because Skeptics requires that a question attributes the claim to a notable source. Please repost this on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com and tell them the source where this image is from. Alternative, you could find a quote of a well-known Jokowi follower or a media outlet which makes the claim.

Comment: Okay I will. The sources are in Indonesia. Also it has strong political nuance. You sure it doesn't belong here?

Comment: Change did Jokowi.... to How can  Jokowi... The did Jokowi... will be copied to skeptic . What do you think?